How to handle a socket being closed after 10000 requests without triggering an error?
I'm trying to create a local HTTP proxy server to throttle HTTPS requests from multiple processes to the same remote server.
I'm using the example in this page as template for the HTTP proxy server and the example in this other page as the template for the HTTPS requests.
This setup is working, including setting up a custom Agent to keep the connection active (as per Antoine Vastel's code). The odd thing is in processes executing tasks that run for days making requests, the processes are exiting prematurely, without errors. I setup a bunch of event listeners to try and catch any clue to this behavior and this is what I get:

On the server side, the remote socket srvSocket emits a close and an end event
On the client side the agent socket in the callback }).on('connect', (res, socket) => { emits a close event.
No error events are emitted anywhere I was able to probe.

After some additional testing I found that this abrupt closing happens exactly after 10000 requests are processed, in about 30 minutes. I don't know how I would confirm that this is in fact the underlying reason, but it seems the remote server forcibly closes open connections after they make 10k requests?
Other processes that make intermittent requests (every few minutes) each lasting for only a few seconds or minutes seem to work just fine without interruptions and in these cases the agent socket is closed due to timeout and a new one is created when a new batch of requests are sent and I haven't found any problems in this case.
So maybe I could add some logic to establish a new connection and continue sending requests when the socket is closed? But I'm not sure how I would do that or even if I can send a plain HTTP response when the client is expecting encrypted TLS data?
I was looking at something like this
srvSocket.on('end', () => {
     cltSocket.end('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n\r\n');
})

But this doesn't seem to be working and I don't know if any message can even be sent through when the agent socket is being closed? How can I catch this event to repeat the request or send an HTTP error code downstream to handle?
